# Ligatures in Hoefler with XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, ligatures, mac, hoefler

Using XeLaTeX on OS X 10.6 (texlive installed with MacPorts) I'm not getting any ligatures with Hoefler.

Example code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
\begin{document}
ff fl fi ffl ffi
\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image]

From my understanding Hoefler ought to have ligatures, but they're not showing up.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of TeXLive/XeTeX does MacPorts give you? Your example works fine for me with Mac OS X 10.6 and MacTeX 2010.

Comment: The version string shows:

    This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live/MacPorts 2009_6)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not that the MacPorts version is broken, it is that by default the MacPorts does not include ATSUI. Rebuild the macports version with `sudo port install texlive-bin +atsui` should fix the problem. Note that this forces the binaries to be 32-bit (so make sure all dependency has been built in 32-bit or universal) which is why it is not on by default.

Comment: In case it helps anyone: I achieved this by uninstalling all installed ports, and then running `sudo port install texlive-bin +atsui +x11; sudo port install texlive +doc +medium; sudo port activate texlive-bin @2012_5+atsui+x11` . That worked for me (and gave me proper ligatures in Zapfino, and let me use alternates as per http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33855/15911), but there may well be a quicker way :)

Comment: See also: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/28497

Answer (score 10):

Looks like this is a problem with the macports version of texlive (tried 2009_6 and 2010_0).  Installed texlive with MacTeX and ligatures work now.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
\fontspec[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Rare, Historical}]{Hoefler Text}
```

Note that "common, rare, historical" will enable a whole bunch of ligatures. if you want the standard ff, ffi, ffl, just the "common" option should suffice.

Comment: `Common` is enabled by default; you'll rarely, if ever, have to specify it manually.

Comment: Adding the line:`\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Rare, Historical}]{Hoefler Text}`

Doesn't change the output, but gives this error:

`    Package fontspec Warning: 
        OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Common' (+liga) not available
        for font "Hoefler Text/ICU", 
        with script 'Latin',
        and language 'Default'.
    This warning occured on input line 6.`
    
(and similar for Rare and Historical)

Comment: P.S. I don't get the `'Ligatures=Common' (+liga) not available` error without the `Ligatures={Common}` option manually enabled.

Comment: are you using the Hoefler Text included with OS X?

Comment: Yes---this is the default Hoefler Text that came with the OS (Fontbook identifies it as `Hoefler Text; 6.1d7e1; 2009-09-21`)