# Hoefler Text Extended Ligatures and XeTeX

Tags: xetex, ligatures, mac, hoefler

I'm using XeTeX (MacTex 2010, Mac OSX 10.6) to render a document in Apple Hoefler Text. However, although I can make it render common ligatures, such as fi and ffi, I can't seem to be able to force it using some extended ligatures as those displayed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rare_and_ancient_ligatures_in_XeTeX.svg). Any suggestions? Here's the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
\fontspec[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Rare, Historic}]{Hoefler Text}

\begin{document}\noindent
Que dictes vous de mon appel, \\
Toute beste garde sa pel \\
Qui la constraint, efforce ou lie
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Ligatures in Hoefler with XeTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6277/1235)

Comment: It seems the duplicated article is only focused on rendering *any* ligatures, while my question is about rendering the extended family of ligatures.

Comment: Are you running OSX 10.5.x or 10.6.x?

Comment: @morbusg: Just added the MacTex and OSX versions.

Comment: does it work if you replace `\fontspec` with `\setmainfont`?

Comment: @Philipp: It worked :-) Bust just for the 'st', 'ct' ligatures. The long tail of the capital Q remains to be shown. Could you please give it as an answer so I can vote up?

Comment: You might need to update your TeX packages; also try 'Historical' in place of 'Historic', though both *should* work unless you're using an old version of fontspec.

Comment: @frabjous: ! Package xkeyval Error: `Historical' undefined in families `Ligatures'.

Comment: Well, that *does* sound like an old version of fontspec then: [see here](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2010-September/018106.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to compile the examples given by Dario Taraborelli on his page, [The Beauty of LATEX](http://nitens.org/taraborelli/latex#rare), especially the [Hoefler sample](http://nitens.org/img/latex/docs/beauty_of_latex_ancient2.pdf)? It seems to work for me (OS X 10.6, TexLive 2010). The trick is to pass `Alternate=1` to `\fontspec` (see the `fontspec` documentation with e.g. `texdoc`), as in

```
\fontspec[Ligatures={Common, Rare}, Alternate=1]{Hoefler Text}
\fontsize{24pt}{30pt}\selectfont 
\noindent
Que dictes vous de mon appel, \\
Toute beste garde sa pel \\
Qui la constraint, efforce ou lie\
```

for the third paragraph below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Do you know how to disable the Alternate for \emphs{} and keep it for normal font?

Comment: Found the answer: `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, ItalicFeatures={Alternate = 0}, Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic},Alternate=1]{Hoefler Text}`

Answer (score 2):

For me

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common, Rare}]{Hoefler Text}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Que dictes vous de mon appel, \\
Toute beste garde sa pel \\
Qui la constraint, efforce ou lie
\end{document}
```

works but something like

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
\fontspec[Ligatures={Common, Rare}]{Hoefler Text}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Que dictes vous de mon appel, \\
Toute beste garde sa pel \\
Qui la constraint, efforce ou lie
\end{document}
```

does not. So you need to watch that you set your font features with the main loading, if you do it in the preamble (all is fine if you put `\fontspec[Ligatures={Common, Rare}]{Hoefler Text}` after `\begin{document}`).

Comment: (+1) That's very nice because I've look for old sample code where I saw that behavior but without any success....

Answer (score 1):

With Hoefler Text Pro 1.201 you need to type `\fontspec{Style = Historic, Ligatures = Historic}{Hoefler Text Pro}`

However, if you are uncertain of the features your font contains, you are better off checking what features your font has, one solution is FontLab Studio or fontForge. Then check how to enable such features, on section 15 "*OpenType Features*" in the [fontspec documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf); there's a table in page 37, listing all supported features. If for whatever reason there are features you would like to use, but are not supported by `fontspec`, you can add them using the `\newopentypefeature` command, explained on section 22 "*Defining new features*".

As to adding new features to your specific font file you might want to check [FontLab Studio](https://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/), [fontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) or Adobe's [AFDKO](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko.html), and resolve to checking Adobe's [documentation on OpenType features](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic_feature_file_syntax.html).

Comment: Are you sure that you need to set a `Style` attribute?

Comment: It loads the long S for me, I dont know if you're on a mac the font is different

Comment: @TeXnician I hope this updated answer further helps you

Comment: I've been trying Dario Taraborelli's code in MacTex 2020 and it does not work as is anymore, apparently. I haven't been able to fix it.