# xelatex does not find some Hoefler Text ligatures that it used to find

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, mactex, hoefler

I just updated to MacTex 2020, and I get the following error, on a document that was compiling fine yesterday, and without having made any change to the document.

I compile with:

```
xelatex test.tex
```

and get:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test2.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize10pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))))

Package fontspec Warning: AAT feature
(fontspec)                'Ligatures=Common,Rare,Historic,Contextual' (1,2)
(fontspec)                not available in font 'Hoefler Text'.


Package fontspec Warning: AAT feature
(fontspec)                'Ligatures=Common,Rare,Historic,Contextual' (1,4)
(fontspec)                not available in font 'Hoefler Text'.


! LaTeX3 Error: Key 'fontspec-aat/Ligatures' accepts only a fixed set of
(LaTeX3)        choices.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.7

?
```

where test.tex is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec, xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, ItalicFeatures={Alternate = 0}, 
Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic,Contextual},Contextuals=Inner,Alternate=1]{Hoefler Text}

\begin{document}
ff fi ffi ct st
\end{document}
```

What should I do to fix this?

***Addendum*** Adding `Renderer=OpenType` removes the error messages when compiling **but** the `ct` and `st` ligatures are lost.

***Addendum*** 2 The .tex files on this (old) [page](http://nitens.org/taraborelli/latex#rare) don't compile anymore either, and when using `Renderer=OpenType`, do not show the ligatures and swashes it used to. So, something has been lost/is not backward compatible, apparently.

***Addendum*** 3 This related [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10495/hoefler-text-extended-ligatures-and-xetex) doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: the first step is a small but *complete* document that can be used for a test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - changed document to be _complete_ and _small_.

Comment: Hm, I don't have a mac and so also not your font. But ligatures  Historic and Contextual are not defined as aat-features and as far as I can see never were. It looks as if fontspec is now using the aat renderer for your font but previously didn't. But I'm not sure why. Are you using xelatex?

Comment: Yes, I am using xelatex. I'm wondering if I should go back to LaTeX 2019. Following the fontspec doc and removing Historic and Contextual compiles, but there are no ligatures to be seen in the document either.

Comment: Try to force the opentype renderer with `Renderer=OpenType`.

Comment: Didn't work :-/ Same error.

Comment: what means didn't work? Did you still get the error about the ligatures?

Comment: Yes, same error.

Comment: What features can `otfinfo -f` on the font file detect?

Comment: For now, I have only found an Apple provided system font file which is `.ttc` and not `.otf`.

Comment: I asked someone with a mac and she said the error did go away with `Renderer=OpenType`.

Comment: I used `\setmainfont[Renderer=OpenType, Mapping=tex-text, ItalicFeatures={Alternate = 0}, 
Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic,Contextual},Contextuals=Inner,Alternate=1]{Hoefler Text}` and all went well. Fully updated TeX Live 2020, via MacTeX, under macOS Catalina 10.15.5.

Comment: @HerbSchulz - can you share the line you used to compile? And also, where is the Hoefler Text font on your machine? And also, you are seeing ligatures in the rendered document, right?

Comment: I'm re-installing TeX Live 2020 from scratch.

Comment: Just compiling with xelatex. What ligatures were you expecting? I added a word with an fi ligature and it appeared correctly.

Comment: I was also getting all the usual ligatures for "st", "ct" ... before running into these troubles.

Comment: Still no luck after re-installing MacTex/TeX Live 2020, Catalina 10.15.4. I'm updating the original post with the full trace from executing xelatex.

Comment: Oh - so with `Renderer=OpenType`, no more error message, but the "st" and "ct" ligatures are lost. That is not good.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the AAT renderer works properly any more with XeTeX and/or the old AAT fonts distributed in macOS are no longer functional like they used to be.

On top of that I suspect Hoefler Text is not set up with proper OpenType font tables (it's not the same version as what you would buy from Hoefler).

Without being definitive about it, I think the best option is to look for a new font…

Comment: I've been analysing this a bit. The problem is that `\XeTeXfeaturename` etc. don't yield any string result anymore: `\font\1="Hoefler Text"
\1 ct st Qu \par
\def\aatfeatures{\XeTeXfeaturename\1 1 =\XeTeXselectorname\1 1 4; \XeTeXfeaturename\1 17=\XeTeXselectorname\1 17 1}
\aatfeatures\par
\font\2="Hoefler Text/AAT:\aatfeatures"
\2 ct st Qu
\bye` This works for me with TL18, but not with TL20

Comment: ... Strangely, you can still select the features manually, if you know their names: `\def\aatfeatures{Ligatures=Rare Ligatures;Character Alternates=Alternates}
\font\3="Hoefler Text/AAT:\aatfeatures"
\3 ct st Qu \bye` (The feature names are font- and system-dependent, e.g. on a German Mac it's `Ligaturen=Seltene Ligaturen; Zeichen-Varianten=Alternativen`)

Comment: But apart from the warning in the `fontspec` doc (in the section "macOS’s AAT fonts") I couldn't find any official notice of depreciation. Would a bug report be worthwhile?

Comment: @Robert - what is the route for a bug report?

Comment: @Robert — perhaps. XeTeX is basically in maintenance mode now, however... I doubt there are any Mac developers that know enough about XeTeX to help out any more :(

Comment: @Frank I've reported it [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/174/). Let's wait and see...

Comment: Thanks! Thanks for checking it out and for reporting it :-)

Comment: If XeTeX is in maintenance mode, is there anything replacing it?

Comment: @Frank you could try with lualatex + harfmode (Renderer=AAT).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Curiously, if I load the font with `\font\1={HoeflerText:mode=harf;shaper=coretext_aat}` or `\font\1={HoeflerText:mode=harf;shaper=graphite2}` and compile with `luahbtex`, the pdf is completely empty, even though there is no error message and `\show\1` shows the expected definition. Compiling with `luatex` succeeds, however, still no rare ligatures.

Comment: @Robert sorry as I don't have the font and a mac I'm out here. But you could add an issue to the luaotfload tracker, perhaps Marcel has an idea.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, it's [here](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/155)

Comment: As a side note, even Microsoft Word seems to be doing the rare ligatures correctly with the Hoefler Text provided by MacOS.

Comment: @Frank Exploiting the fact that you can still select the features by name, the following works for me (yielding ct and st ligatures as well as a Q with a swash): `\setmainfont[RawFeature={Ligatures=Rare Ligatures;Character Alternates=Alternates}]{Hoefler Text}`

Comment: @Robert - Thank you! I can confirm that indeed it does work with MacTex 2020, and the "native" Hoefler Text fonts, with xelatex.

Comment: Any suggestions how to do this with smallcaps?

Comment: @MarkPorter `\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Hoefler Text},SmallCapsFeatures={RawFeature={Letter Case=Small Caps}}]{Hoefler Text}` works for me.