# Expansion: argument of \input handled differently on Windows and Linux

Tags: expansion, input

Consider the following files `main.tex` and `xyz.tex`:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\abc{XYZ.tex}
\input{\MakeLowercase{\abc}}
\end{document}

% xyz.tex (all lowercase letters)
Hey, it works!
```

LaTeXing `main.tex` works under Windows (would even work without trying to lowercase the filename, as filenames are case-insensitive), while under Linux, it gives the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `MakeLowercase {XYZ.tex}' not found.
```

**Question:** Why does it work under Windows, even though `\MakeLowercase` is not expandable? Shouldn't we expect identical behavior across OSes? What would it take to treat macros the same in both cases?

*(I know how to achieve the desired effect of lowercasing the filename, by using e.g. `\explower` from the post [Expandably change letter case and use inside \csname, without a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173481/expandably-change-letter-case-and-use-inside-csname-without-a-package).)*

Comment: MakeLowercase is really the wrong command.

Comment: are you sure it is the OS rather than latex release? MakeUppercase was re-implemented recently. I am highly surprised either implementation worked

Comment: @DavidCarlisle on windows it fails in texlive 2021, but works in texlive 2022.

Comment: where "works" means some accidental sequence of expansions does something approximating the behaviour intended?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your comments. I'm aware that MakeLowercase is not appropriate, but I'm still surprised that Windows does not issue an error.

Comment: Under Windows, it is a recently updated MiKTeX, under Linux it is TeXLive 2022.

Comment: is your tl 2022 up to date, as egreg shows it should work with a June release I think

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's it. After updating all package of my TL2022, it now also seems to work under Linux. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what happens on my machine (with a case-sensitive, sort of, file system).

With TL 2022 it *seems* to work, but I wouldn't rely on it.

##### TeX Live 2022

```
! LaTeX Error: File `xyz.tex' not found.
```

##### TeX Live 2021

```
! LaTeX Error: File `MakeLowercase {XYZ.tex}' not found.
```

##### TeX Live 2020

Hangs

##### TeX Live 2019

```
! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   protect
l.4 \input{\MakeLowercase{\abc}}
```

##### TeX Live 2018 and earlier

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@filef@und.
<to be read again>

l.4 \input{\MakeLowercase{\abc}}
```

---

With a recent LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\lowercaseinput}{m}
 {
  \file_input:e { \str_lowercase:e { #1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \file_input:n { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_lowercase:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\newcommand\abc{XYZ.tex}

\lowercaseinput{\abc}

\renewcommand\abc{XÝŽ.tex}

\lowercaseinput{\abc}

\end{document}
```

Note that this should also work with (most) UTF-8 characters. The console will show

```
! LaTeX Error: File 'xyz.tex' not found.

! LaTeX Error: File 'xýž.tex' not found.
```

Answer (score 7):

We can see that LaTeX macros are changed from year to year. But TeX primitives keep unchanged. You can solve your problem by TeX primitive `\lowercase`:

```
\lowercase \expandafter{\expandafter\input \expandafter{\abc}}
```

If we have `\def\abc{XYX.tex}` then the command above is transformed to

```
\input {xyz.tex}
```

Win systems use case insensitive access to the file names(?), so it works without `\lowercase` too.

Comment: try that with a filename with non-ascii characters, `\MakeLowercase` has access to the full Unicode mapping, even with pdflatex

Comment: pdftex is obsolete engine because it doesn't support Unicode.