# Lualatex: Change the colour of a specific character

Tags: color, luatex, strings

This is similar to [Change the color of capital letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173209/change-the-color-of-capital-letters) and the MWE below is modelled on egreg's answer.  It works up to the point of correctly changing the first character in the input string.  What I now want to do is pass a second parameter indicating which character of the string to change i.e. instead of `\capme{AVXxx}` I want to be able to write e.g. `\capme{AVXxx}{V}` and have only the colour of the "V" change.
The initial string will have a maximum of *8 ASCII* letters, it will always contain exactly one letter matching the second parameter (so, in that example, its only valid value is one of A, V or X).

I've tried to pass the first parameter to the string "s" and the second parameter to the string "l" but even hardcoding "l" as "V" isn't working.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function wrap(s, l)
l="[%uV]"
s=" "..s -- The first letter may also change
s=unicode.utf8.gsub(s, "([%s{])("..l..")", "%1\\colorlead{%2}")
s=unicode.utf8.sub(s,2) -- Delete leading space
tex.print(s) 
end -- function wrap
\end{luacode*}

\def\capme#1{\directlua{wrap([[#1]])}}

\begin{document}

\def\colorlead#1{{\color{red}#1}}

\capme{AVXxx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you don't need Lua at all. The following code just recurses over the first argument characters and colors those which match the second argument. Also, I've added a simple Lua based command as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function wrap(s, l)
s=unicode.utf8.gsub(s, l, "\\colorlead{%1}")
tex.print(s) 
end
\end{luacode*}

\def\luacapme#1#2{\directlua{wrap([[#1]],[[#2]])}}

\makeatletter
\def\capme#1#2{\@capme{#2}#1\relax}

\def\@capme#1#2{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\relax}{#2}}{%
    \let\next\relax
  }{%
    \def\next{\@capme{#1}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{#1}}{%
      \colorlead{#2}%
    }{%
      #2%
  }}\next
}
\makeatother

\def\colorlead#1{{\color{red}#1}}

\begin{document}
\luacapme{AVXxx}{A}

\luacapme{AVXxx}{V}

\luacapme{AVXxx}{x}
\end{document}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

Comment: It's certainly possible without Lua - it just seemed that it should be easy to do that sort of string matching in Lua :-(

Comment: If it's an exercise in Lua then I've added `\luacapme` which does a simple substitution in Lua. It isn't intended to use patterns in place of the second argument.

Comment: Excellent.  It was sort of a learning experiment to meet an actual need.

Answer (score 1):

Also without `lua`; however, it breaks the natural interletter kerning when color change takes place.

It works by creating, at each invocation, a new version of the macro `\capmeaux`, which sets itself up to parse with `#2` as the divider.  Thus, `\capme{AVXxx}{A}`  creates the definition

```
\def\capmeaux#1A#2\relax{#1\textcolor{\colorlead}{A}#2}
```

and then proceeds to invoke it with `\capmeaux AVXxx\relax`

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\colorlead{red}
\newcommand\capme[2]{%
  \def\capmeaux##1#2##2\relax{##1\textcolor{\colorlead}{#2}##2}\capmeaux#1\relax}
\begin{document}
\capme{AVXxx}{A}

\capme{AVXxx}{V}

\capme{AVXxx}{X}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kerning isn't an issue for these sequences.