# LuaLaTeX Error: Missing characters which are in the fonts used

Tags: symbols, luatex, fontspec, unicode

when I let LuaLaTeX process input files which contain certain rather unusual Unicode glyphs, some of them do not show up. Instead, there is a warning message in the log:

Missing character: There is no __ (U+____) in font ____!

This happens with different fonts. Curiously however, it depends on the font which glyphs won't show. I checked and the glyphs used definitely do exist in the fonts; they show up in the character map.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setromanfont{Cambria}

\title{Minimal Working Example for Missing Unicode Glyphs}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

A number of symbols are “not found” – what works and what not depends on the font selected, see tables~\ref{tab_list1}, \ref{tab_list2}, and \ref{tab_list3} for examples. Note that for the font OpenSymbol, normal letters don't work!

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{rlcrl}
        Check Mark      &   ✓   &   &   Hour Glass          &   ⌛   \\
        Not Checked     &   ✗   &   &   Neutral Smiley      &     \\
        Happy Smiley    &   ☺   &   &   Gear                &   ⚙   \\
        Sad Smiley      &   ☹   &   &                   &       \\
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab_list1}
    \caption{A list of Unicode symbols – for font Cambria.}
\end{table}

\setromanfont{OpenSymbol}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{rlcrl}
        Check Mark      &   ✓   &   &   Hour Glass          &   ⌛   \\
        Not Checked     &   ✗   &   &   Neutral Smiley      &     \\
        Happy Smiley    &   ☺   &   &   Gear                &   ⚙   \\
        Sad Smiley      &   ☹   &   &                   &       \\
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab_list2}
    \caption{A list of Unicode symbols – for font OpenSymbol.}
\end{table}

\setromanfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{rlcrl}
        Check Mark      &   ✓   &   &   Hour Glass          &   ⌛   \\
        Not Checked     &   ✗   &   &   Neutral Smiley      &     \\
        Happy Smiley    &   ☺   &   &   Gear                &   ⚙   \\
        Sad Smiley      &   ☹   &   &                   &       \\
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab_list3}
    \caption{A list of Unicode symbols – for font DejaVu Sans.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here are some excerpts from the log produced on my system, Linux Mint 17.3 with TeXLive 2016:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)  (format=lualatex 2016.6.27)  28 JUN 2016 10:30
 restricted system commands enabled.
**mwe.tex
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
```

[...]

```
Package: fontspec 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty
Package: luaotfload 2016/06/16 v2.7 OpenType layout system
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2016/06/16 2.70003 OpenType layout system.
Lua module: lualibs 2016-04-06 2.4 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2016-04-06 2.4 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended co
llection.(using write cache: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/ge
neric)(using read cache: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic 
/home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/
luatex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2016-06-16.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontl
oader-2016-06-16.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.023”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/
luatex-cache/generic/names.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.088 seconds)
Lua module: fontspec 2016/02/01 2.5a Advanced font selection for LuaLaTeX.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l_fontspec_script_int=\count115
\l_fontspec_language_int=\count116
\l_fontspec_strnum_int=\count117
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2enc.def
File: eu2enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU2+lmr on input line 105.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmr.fd
File: eu2lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/roland/.texlive2016/texm
f-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc(compiling luc: /usr/local/
texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc)(loa
d luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroma
n10-regular.luc))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many o
ther characters in Unicode lower plane

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/lmromanslant10-regular.luc)(load luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luate
x-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmromanslant10-regular.luc)(compiling luc: /usr/local/
texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-italic.luc)(load
 luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman
10-italic.luc)(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gen
eric/fonts/otl/lmroman10-bold.luc)(load luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var
/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-bold.luc)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU2+lmss on input line 357.


(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmss.fd
File: eu2lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/ot
l/lmsans10-regular.luc)(load luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cac
he/generic/fonts/otl/lmsans10-regular.luc))
\tipaTiiicode=\count118
\tipasavetokens=\toks14
\tipachecktokens=\toks15
```

[...]

```
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-va
r/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.(compiling luc: /usr/lo
cal/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/cambria-1.luc)(load lu
c: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/cambria-1.
luc)
\g__fontspec_family_Cambria_int=\count123
(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/cambriaz.luc)(load luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generi
c/fonts/otl/cambriaz.luc)(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luate
x-cache/generic/fonts/otl/cambriab.luc)(load luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texm
f-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/cambriab.luc)(compiling luc: /usr/local/tex
live/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/cambriai.luc)(load luc: /home
/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/cambriai.luc)
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'Cambria(0)' created for font 'Cambria' with options
. [Ligatures=TeX].
. 
. This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Cambria:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Cambria:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+smcp;"- 'bold' (bx/n)
. with NFSS spec.: <->"Cambria/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Cambria/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+smcp;"- 'italic'
. (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Cambria/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;"
. - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Cambria/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+smcp;"- 'bold
. italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Cambria/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;"
. - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Cambria/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+smcp;"
.................................................
 (./mwe.aux)
\openout1 = mwe.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU2/lmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 9.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
```

[...]

```
LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 16.
(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/opens-.luc)(load luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/
fonts/otl/opens-.luc)
luaotfload | aux : font no 50 (<unknown>) defines no feature for script latn
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 50
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-scripts"
. 
. Font OpenSymbol does not contain any OpenType `Script' information.
.................................................
\g__fontspec_family_OpenSymbol_int=\count130
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font OpenSymbol/BI (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font OpenSymbol/B (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font OpenSymbol/I (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
luaotfload | aux : font no 50 (<unknown>) does not define feature smcp for scrip
t  with language 
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 50
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'OpenSymbol(0)' created for font 'OpenSymbol' with options
. [Ligatures=TeX].
. 
. This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
.................................................
(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/dejavusans.luc)(load luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gene
ric/fonts/otl/dejavusans.luc)
\g__fontspec_family_DejaVuSans_int=\count131
(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/dejavusans-boldoblique.luc)(load luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luate
x-cache/generic/fonts/otl/dejavusans-boldoblique.luc)(compiling luc: /usr/local/
texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/dejavusans-bold.luc)(load 
luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/dejavusa
ns-bold.luc)(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gener
ic/fonts/otl/dejavusans-oblique.luc)(load luc: /home/roland/.texlive2016/texmf-v
ar/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/dejavusans-oblique.luc)
luaotfload | aux : font no 52 (<unknown>) does not define feature smcp for scrip
t latn with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 52
luaotfload | aux : font no 54 (<unknown>) does not define feature smcp for scrip
t latn with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 54
luaotfload | aux : font no 55 (<unknown>) does not define feature smcp for scrip
t latn with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 55
luaotfload | aux : font no 53 (<unknown>) does not define feature smcp for scrip
t latn with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 53
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'DejaVuSans(0)' created for font 'DejaVu Sans' with options
. [Ligatures=TeX].
. 
. This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"DejaVuSans:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"DejaVuSans/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS
. spec.: <->"DejaVuSans/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;"
. - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: - 'bold italic' (bx/it)
. with NFSS spec.:
. <->"DejaVuSans/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;"
. - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
.................................................
 [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
Missing character: There is no ✓ (U+2713) in font Cambria:mode=node;script=lat
n;language=DFLT;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ✗ (U+2717) in font Cambria:mode=node;script=lat
n;language=DFLT;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no  (U+1F610) in font Cambria:mode=node;script=l
atn;language=DFLT;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ☺ (U+263A) in font Cambria:mode=node;script=lat
n;language=DFLT;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ⚙ (U+2699) in font Cambria:mode=node;script=lat
n;language=DFLT;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ☹ (U+2639) in font Cambria:mode=node;script=lat
n;language=DFLT;+tlig;!
] [2
Missing character: There is no C (U+0043) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no h (U+0068) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no c (U+0063) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no k (U+006B) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no M (U+004D) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no a (U+0061) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no r (U+0072) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no k (U+006B) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no H (U+0048) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no o (U+006F) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no u (U+0075) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no r (U+0072) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no G (U+0047) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no a (U+0061) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no s (U+0073) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no s (U+0073) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ⌛ (U+231B) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no N (U+004E) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no o (U+006F) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no t (U+0074) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no C (U+0043) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no h (U+0068) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no c (U+0063) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no k (U+006B) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no d (U+0064) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no N (U+004E) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no u (U+0075) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no t (U+0074) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no r (U+0072) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no a (U+0061) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no S (U+0053) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no m (U+006D) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no i (U+0069) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no y (U+0079) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no  (U+1F610) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig
;!
Missing character: There is no H (U+0048) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no a (U+0061) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no p (U+0070) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no p (U+0070) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no y (U+0079) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no S (U+0053) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no m (U+006D) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no i (U+0069) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no y (U+0079) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no G (U+0047) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no a (U+0061) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no r (U+0072) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ⚙ (U+2699) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no S (U+0053) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no a (U+0061) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no d (U+0064) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no S (U+0053) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no m (U+006D) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no i (U+0069) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no y (U+0079) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no T (U+0054) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no a (U+0061) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no b (U+0062) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no 2 (U+0032) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no A (U+0041) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no i (U+0069) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no s (U+0073) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no t (U+0074) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no o (U+006F) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no f (U+0066) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no U (U+0055) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no n (U+006E) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no i (U+0069) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no c (U+0063) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no o (U+006F) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no d (U+0064) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no s (U+0073) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no y (U+0079) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no m (U+006D) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no b (U+0062) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no o (U+006F) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no s (U+0073) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no f (U+0066) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no o (U+006F) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no r (U+0072) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no f (U+0066) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no o (U+006F) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no n (U+006E) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no t (U+0074) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no O (U+004F) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no p (U+0070) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no n (U+006E) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no S (U+0053) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no y (U+0079) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no m (U+006D) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no b (U+0062) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no o (U+006F) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font OpenSymbol:mode=node;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ⌛ (U+231B) in font DejaVuSans:mode=node;script=
latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;!
] (./mwe.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 14447 strings out of 495118
 100000,319454 words of node,token memory allocated
 479 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 16 glue, 9 attribute, 44 glue_spec, 9 attribute_lis
t, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:405,3:33,4:8,5:55,6:612,7:492,8:15,9:117,10:7,11:43
 17652 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 56 fonts using 17966183 bytes
 50i,7n,62p,319b,231s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
</usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice/opens___.ttf></usr/local/texlive/2016/texm
f-dist/fonts/truetype/public/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf></home/roland/.local/share/fo
nts/cambria.ttc>
Output written on mwe.pdf (2 pages, 47788 bytes).

PDF statistics: 32 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 18 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I hope someone of you knows something about this...

Comment: The character map is not a prove -- the OS sometimes fills up such Maps with fallback fonts. Also it is quite normal that different fonts have different glyph coverage. With the newest luaotfload you can build up combo fonts and pull in missing glyphs from other fonts, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314397/defining-new-font-family-with-fontspec/314401#314401.

Comment: Ahh, thank you – that's it. In the character map, I had to activate the option "Show only glyphs from this font", and now, the characters not showing up in the PDF are not pretending to be there any more. I could have continued to fool myself for a loong time...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is only apparent as the characters in question actually are not in the font (and were shown by a feature of the system application that wasn't turned off)