# Get font Alegreya working with greek letters

Tags: fonts, greek

Is there a way to substitute greek letters -- which are not available in Alegreya -- *automatically*  with greek letters from another font?
I am aware of a solution to put all greek letters into a macro and define a different font for that, but this is not intended.

I was able to use `libertine` for greek letters in `\sffamily` but this doesn’t work für `\normalfont`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{libertine}% to substitute greek in \sffamily
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya}
\begin{document}
1234567890
\subsection*{greek normalfont}
μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληϊάδεω Ἀχιλῆος
οὐλομένην, ἣ μυρί᾽ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε᾽ ἔθηκε,
πολλὰς δ᾽ ἰφθίμους ψυχὰς Ἄϊδι προΐαψεν
ἡρώων, αὐτοὺς δὲ ἑλώρια τεῦχε κύνεσσιν
οἰωνοῖσί τε πᾶσι, Διὸς δ᾽ ἐτελείετο βουλή,
ἐξ οὗ δὴ τὰ πρῶτα διαστήτην ἐρίσαντε
Ἀτρεΐδης τε ἄναξ ἀνδρῶν καὶ δῖος Ἀχιλλεύς.
τίς τ᾽ ἄρ σφωε θεῶν ἔριδι ξυνέηκε μάχεσθαι;
Λητοῦς καὶ Διὸς υἱός: ὃ γὰρ βασιλῆϊ χολωθεὶς
νοῦσον ἀνὰ στρατὸν ὄρσε κακήν, ὀλέκοντο δὲ λαοί,
οὕνεκα τὸν Χρύσην ἠτίμασεν ἀρητῆρα
Ἀτρεΐδης: ὃ γὰρ ἦλθε θοὰς ἐπὶ νῆας Ἀχαιῶν
λυσόμενός τε θύγατρα φέρων τ᾽ ἀπερείσι᾽ ἄποινα,
στέμματ᾽ ἔχων ἐν χερσὶν ἑκηβόλου Ἀπόλλωνος
χρυσέῳ ἀνὰ σκήπτρῳ, καὶ λίσσετο πάντας Ἀχαιούς,
Ἀτρεΐδα δὲ μάλιστα δύω, κοσμήτορε λαῶν:
Ἀτρεΐδαι τε καὶ ἄλλοι ἐϋκνήμιδες Ἀχαιοί,
ὑμῖν μὲν θεοὶ δοῖεν Ὀλύμπια δώματ᾽ ἔχοντες
ἐκπέρσαι Πριάμοιο πόλιν, εὖ δ᾽ οἴκαδ᾽ ἱκέσθαι:
παῖδα δ᾽ ἐμοὶ λύσαιτε φίλην, τὰ δ᾽ ἄποινα δέχεσθαι,
ἁζόμενοι Διὸς υἱὸν ἑκηβόλον Ἀπόλλωνα.



\subsection*{greek sffamily}
\sffamily
μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληϊάδεω Ἀχιλῆος
οὐλομένην, ἣ μυρί᾽ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε᾽ ἔθηκε,
πολλὰς δ᾽ ἰφθίμους ψυχὰς Ἄϊδι προΐαψεν
ἡρώων, αὐτοὺς δὲ ἑλώρια τεῦχε κύνεσσιν
οἰωνοῖσί τε πᾶσι, Διὸς δ᾽ ἐτελείετο βουλή,
ἐξ οὗ δὴ τὰ πρῶτα διαστήτην ἐρίσαντε
Ἀτρεΐδης τε ἄναξ ἀνδρῶν καὶ δῖος Ἀχιλλεύς.
τίς τ᾽ ἄρ σφωε θεῶν ἔριδι ξυνέηκε μάχεσθαι;
Λητοῦς καὶ Διὸς υἱός: ὃ γὰρ βασιλῆϊ χολωθεὶς
νοῦσον ἀνὰ στρατὸν ὄρσε κακήν, ὀλέκοντο δὲ λαοί,
οὕνεκα τὸν Χρύσην ἠτίμασεν ἀρητῆρα
Ἀτρεΐδης: ὃ γὰρ ἦλθε θοὰς ἐπὶ νῆας Ἀχαιῶν
λυσόμενός τε θύγατρα φέρων τ᾽ ἀπερείσι᾽ ἄποινα,
στέμματ᾽ ἔχων ἐν χερσὶν ἑκηβόλου Ἀπόλλωνος
χρυσέῳ ἀνὰ σκήπτρῳ, καὶ λίσσετο πάντας Ἀχαιούς,
Ἀτρεΐδα δὲ μάλιστα δύω, κοσμήτορε λαῶν:
Ἀτρεΐδαι τε καὶ ἄλλοι ἐϋκνήμιδες Ἀχαιοί,
ὑμῖν μὲν θεοὶ δοῖεν Ὀλύμπια δώματ᾽ ἔχοντες
ἐκπέρσαι Πριάμοιο πόλιν, εὖ δ᾽ οἴκαδ᾽ ἱκέσθαι:
παῖδα δ᾽ ἐμοὶ λύσαιτε φίλην, τὰ δ᾽ ἄποινα δέχεσθαι,
ἁζόμενοι Διὸς υἱὸν ἑκηβόλον Ἀπόλλωνα.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With luaotfload you can build combo fonts, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314397/defining-new-font-family-with-fontspec/314401#314401. But there is no high-level interface yet.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How could it look like with the example you referenced to?

Comment: You only need to exchange the file names (`\font \one = file:Alegreya-Regular.ttf \font \two = file:LinBiolinum_R.otf`) and the range `2 -> \fontid \two , 0x370-0x3FF;`. But as I said: it is not high-level, so you can't use size commands like `\large` or change the series with `\bfseries`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! You’re solution works almost quite well (besides to changes you mention) but the range is too small, since characters with diacritics are missing.

Comment: I made only a fast search for "unicode greek range", you can adapt it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It works with the range `0x370-0x1FFF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specific to your current problem, the latest versions of Alegreya actually come with complete polytonic Greek support.

If you are in a position to update your TeX distribution, updating to the latest version of the Alegreya package should solve the problem.

Otherwise, you may download the fonts from https://www.huertatipografica.com/en/fonts/alegreya-ht-pro and include it in your document with something like the following, assuming that you are using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alegreya}[
Extension = .otf,
UprightFont = *-Regular,
ItalicFont = *-Italic,
BoldFont = *-Bold,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
Ligatures = TeX
]
\setsansfont{Alegreya}[
Extension = .otf,
UprightFont = *-Regular,
ItalicFont = *-Italic,
BoldFont = *-Bold,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
Ligatures = TeX
]
```

To use the other weights, useful when typesetting headings and list numbers, page numbers, etc, it is best to define additional font families. For example,

```
\newfontfamily\alegreyablack{Alegreya}[
Extension = .otf,
UprightFont = *-ExtreBold,
ItalicFont = *-ExtraBoldItalicItalic,
BoldFont = *-Black,
BoldItalicFont = *-BlackItalic,
Ligatures = TeX
]
```

Then you can switch font families by the `\alegreyablack` macro, which behaves similar to the usual variant switching macros like `\itshape` and `\bfseries`; thus delimit the scope of the macro by introducing it only in nested contexts; for example, `normal font {\alegreyablack bold font} normal font`. Alternatively, reset to the body text settings with `\normalfont`.

Then the fonts will be used if it is in the right path in the distribution, or installed in some manner or other (local or system-wide) in your OS. This is my preferred way to use OTF files, since it gives better control over the OTF features.

You can find more customization options for using OTF files in your document in the `fontspec` documentation.

P.S. The Greek letters in Alegreya are (in my opinion) far more beautiful than the ones in Libertine.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I wasn’t aware of the font-update. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @UlrikeFischer I found a working solution unless you need a different command like changing the size or font (`\large` or `bfseries`).

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{libertine}% to substitute greek in \sffamily
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya}

\font \alegreya = file:Alegreya-Regular.ttf 
\font \libertine = file:LinBiolinum_R.otf
\font \alegreyalibertine = "combo: 1 -> \fontid \alegreya ;
                       2 -> \fontid \libertine , 0x370-0x1FFF;"
\AtBeginDocument\alegreyalibertine                                              

\begin{document}
\subsection*{greek normalfont}
μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληϊάδεω Ἀχιλῆος
οὐλομένην, ἣ μυρί᾽ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε᾽ ἔθηκε,
πολλὰς δ᾽ ἰφθίμους ψυχὰς Ἄϊδι προΐαψεν
ἡρώων, αὐτοὺς δὲ ἑλώρια τεῦχε κύνεσσιν
οἰωνοῖσί τε πᾶσι, Διὸς δ᾽ ἐτελείετο βουλή,
ἐξ οὗ δὴ τὰ πρῶτα διαστήτην ἐρίσαντε
Ἀτρεΐδης τε ἄναξ ἀνδρῶν καὶ δῖος Ἀχιλλεύς.
τίς τ᾽ ἄρ σφωε θεῶν ἔριδι ξυνέηκε μάχεσθαι;
Λητοῦς καὶ Διὸς υἱός: ὃ γὰρ βασιλῆϊ χολωθεὶς
νοῦσον ἀνὰ στρατὸν ὄρσε κακήν, ὀλέκοντο δὲ λαοί,

οὕνεκα τὸν Χρύσην ἠτίμασεν ἀρητῆρα
Ἀτρεΐδης: ὃ γὰρ ἦλθε θοὰς ἐπὶ νῆας Ἀχαιῶν
λυσόμενός τε θύγατρα φέρων τ᾽ ἀπερείσι᾽ ἄποινα,
στέμματ᾽ ἔχων ἐν χερσὶν ἑκηβόλου Ἀπόλλωνος
χρυσέῳ ἀνὰ σκήπτρῳ, καὶ λίσσετο πάντας Ἀχαιούς,
Ἀτρεΐδα δὲ μάλιστα δύω, κοσμήτορε λαῶν:
Ἀτρεΐδαι τε καὶ ἄλλοι ἐϋκνήμιδες Ἀχαιοί,
ὑμῖν μὲν θεοὶ δοῖεν Ὀλύμπια δώματ᾽ ἔχοντες
ἐκπέρσαι Πριάμοιο πόλιν, εὖ δ᾽ οἴκαδ᾽ ἱκέσθαι:
παῖδα δ᾽ ἐμοὶ λύσαιτε φίλην, τὰ δ᾽ ἄποινα δέχεσθαι,
ἁζόμενοι Διὸς υἱὸν ἑκηβόλον Ἀπόλλωνα.



\subsection*{greek sffamily}
\sffamily
μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληϊάδεω Ἀχιλῆος
οὐλομένην, ἣ μυρί᾽ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε᾽ ἔθηκε,
πολλὰς δ᾽ ἰφθίμους ψυχὰς Ἄϊδι προΐαψεν
ἡρώων, αὐτοὺς δὲ ἑλώρια τεῦχε κύνεσσιν
οἰωνοῖσί τε πᾶσι, Διὸς δ᾽ ἐτελείετο βουλή,
ἐξ οὗ δὴ τὰ πρῶτα διαστήτην ἐρίσαντε
Ἀτρεΐδης τε ἄναξ ἀνδρῶν καὶ δῖος Ἀχιλλεύς.
τίς τ᾽ ἄρ σφωε θεῶν ἔριδι ξυνέηκε μάχεσθαι;
Λητοῦς καὶ Διὸς υἱός: ὃ γὰρ βασιλῆϊ χολωθεὶς
νοῦσον ἀνὰ στρατὸν ὄρσε κακήν, ὀλέκοντο δὲ λαοί,

\tiny

οὕνεκα τὸν Χρύσην ἠτίμασεν ἀρητῆρα
Ἀτρεΐδης: ὃ γὰρ ἦλθε θοὰς ἐπὶ νῆας Ἀχαιῶν
λυσόμενός τε θύγατρα φέρων τ᾽ ἀπερείσι᾽ ἄποινα,
στέμματ᾽ ἔχων ἐν χερσὶν ἑκηβόλου Ἀπόλλωνος
χρυσέῳ ἀνὰ σκήπτρῳ, καὶ λίσσετο πάντας Ἀχαιούς,
Ἀτρεΐδα δὲ μάλιστα δύω, κοσμήτορε λαῶν:
Ἀτρεΐδαι τε καὶ ἄλλοι ἐϋκνήμιδες Ἀχαιοί,
ὑμῖν μὲν θεοὶ δοῖεν Ὀλύμπια δώματ᾽ ἔχοντες
ἐκπέρσαι Πριάμοιο πόλιν, εὖ δ᾽ οἴκαδ᾽ ἱκέσθαι:
παῖδα δ᾽ ἐμοὶ λύσαιτε φίλην, τὰ δ᾽ ἄποινα δέχεσθαι,
ἁζόμενοι Διὸς υἱὸν ἑκηβόλον Ἀπόλλωνα.
\end{document}
```

It is no problem if you have greek letters in different sizes with `\sffamily`.

[image]

Comment: Check https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371989/2388 for a description how to activate "size changing commands".