# Set Numbers in Small Caps by Default

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, small-caps

I am using the `fontspec` package with `LuaLaTeX`. I'm curious if there is a way to automatically set numbers in small caps by default similar to how you can set numbers in OldStyle/Lowercase by default via the `fontspec` package options `Numbers=OldStyle` or `Numbers=Lowercase`

Note: Not all fonts support numbers in small caps. I use a free font in my MWE that supports small caps numbers.

My motivation for asking this question is that I am currently testing if typesetting numbers in small caps is easier or nicer to read than the usual uppercased, monospaced numbers. Having an easier way to output numbers in small caps would be wonderful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\alphabet}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\newcommand{\digits}{0123456789}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}%Available for free on Google Fonts.
    [
    %Numbers=OldStyle%
    %Numbers=Lowercase%
    ]
\begin{document}
\textbf{Regular letters and digits:}
\par
\alphabet\quad\digits
\par
\textbf{Small caps letters and digits:}
\par
\textsc{\alphabet\quad\digits}
\par
\textbf{Regular letters and Oldstyle digits:}
\par
\alphabet\quad\oldstylenums{\digits}
\end{document}
```

EDIT 1: I added a photo displaying numbers with small caps.
[image]

EDIT 2: I am looking for a solution, if possible, that makes numbers display as small caps *by default* without having to use `\textsc` or any other in-text macro. Thus, `\textsc{1234}` and `1234` should look identical. If this isn't possible, of course, I can always fall back on making an in-text macro.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "small caps numbers". I only know small caps for letters and old style numbers. Maybe you can post a picture of what you're after? If the font you use indeed supports something like numbers that fit the size of small caps (smaller numbers, so to say, which I assume is about what you mean), then you need to look up the font feature that selects this style in this font. You can then select this style, for example, using the option `RawFeature=+xxxx` where `xxxx` stands for the relevant feature abbreviation.

Comment: I've added a photo that displays how numbers with small caps look like. I hope this clears up some confusion.

Comment: Okay, so ... You want to get these "small caps numbers" by default, without small caps letters surrounding them? Is this what you're after?

Comment: Yes! That is what I want!

Comment: Sorry, I actually have no answer to that. Source Sans Pro does not contain a feature that lets you select only these small numbers without affecting other letters. And on the other hand it seems that it is not possible to only select such features only for numbers using `fontspec`. Maybe you could create a [`combofont`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474209/47927).

Comment: I will probably try making a macro that automatically format numbers with its associated text, e.g. when typing things like 8 hours, 4 to 6 weeks, item 43, class period 2, etc. Maybe this could be useful for more general purposes.

Comment: There are "small caps numbers" in some fonts. One familiar to me, simply has the numerals at small caps size, without the ascenders or descenders found in oldstyle. But in that case (it is a custom font, not public) there is a specific OpenType feature for it. If you look in the `fontspec` documentation, you will see that you can define your own custom feature, where you select specific characters in a font, and give them a new feature name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, what you're after are digits that match small caps in size (which have not really a name to my knowledge, since the term "small caps" is usually only used for letters), but you want them printed in this style regardless of the sourrounding style of the text.

You can select specific OpenType features using `fontspec` via the option `RawFeature=+xxxx` where `xxxx` is the abbreviation of the relevant OpenType feature. So, you could select `RawFeature=+smcp` to enable small caps in general. Sadly, Source Sans Pro does not contain a feature that lets you select only these small numbers without affecting other letters, and on the other hand it seems that it is not directly possible to only select such features only for numbers using `fontspec`.

However, you can use `fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature` and enhance the font with your own custom OpenType feature which you can then use with `fontspec`. In the following example, I created the feature `xnum` which replaces the digit glyphs with the small-caps variants (you'd need to look up the relevant glyph names in the font, though):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "xnum",
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
            ["zero"] = "zero.sc",
            ["one"] = "one.sc",
            ["two"] = "two.sc",
            ["three"] = "three.sc",
            ["four"] = "four.sc",
            ["five"] = "five.sc",
            ["six"] = "six.sc",
            ["seven"] = "seven.sc",
            ["eight"] = "eight.sc",
            ["nine"] = "nine.sc",
        },
    }
}

\setmainfont[RawFeature=+xnum]{Source Serif Pro}

\newcommand{\alphabet}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\newcommand{\digits}{0123456789}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Regular letters and digits:}
\par
\alphabet\quad\digits

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another way would be to create a `combofont` using the package with the same name (which is based on the mechanisms provided by the `luaotfload` package). It is important to note that adding features such as `smcp` to the second font only works with setting `mode=base`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{combofont}
\setupcombofont{sourceserifpro-regular}{
    {name:Source Serif Pro-Regular:mode=base;language=DFLT;+tlig} at #1pt,
    {name:Source Serif Pro-Regular:mode=base;language=DFLT;+tlig;+smcp} at #1pt
}{
    {} ,
    0x30-0x39
}
\setupcombofont{sourceserifpro-bold}{
    {name:Source Serif Pro-Bold:mode=base;language=DFLT;+tlig} at #1pt,
    {name:Source Serif Pro-Bold:mode=base;language=DFLT;+tlig;+smcp} at #1pt
}{
    {} ,
    0x30-0x39
}

\DeclareFontFamily{TU}{sourceserifpro-combo}{}
\DeclareFontShape {TU}{sourceserifpro-combo}{m}{n} {<->combo*sourceserifpro-regular}{}
\DeclareFontShape {TU}{sourceserifpro-combo}{bx}{n}{<->combo*sourceserifpro-bold}{}

\newcommand{\alphabet}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\newcommand{\digits}{0123456789}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{sourceserifpro-combo}\selectfont

\textbf{Regular letters and digits:}
\par
\alphabet\quad\digits

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: "lowercase" is not a traditional printer's term for digits.  (Some people call oldstyle digits lowercase, but this is mistaken.)  In the traditional context, I'm familiar with two pairs of terms: lining/oldstyle and tabular/proportional.  Together they provide four styles.  Either lining or oldstyle can be used in tables, but tabular is essential, as columnar consistency is essential.  Any of the four styles can be used in text.  I doubt that "small caps oldstyle" would be wanted, but the tabular/proportional requirement probably holds.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Maybe not traditional, but certainly it is possible to design digits at the height of small caps, without ascenders or descenders. I have done it. But there is no standard OpenType feature code. It would need to be assigned to a style set (ssNN) which is not the same in every font. Purpose of such digits: Might look better than either lining or oldstyle, when mingled in an extended string of small caps text.

Comment: @rallg Indeed, I also thought that the proper OpenType feature code should maybe something like `ssNN`. Source Serif Pro assigns `ss01` (Bulgarian variants of certain Cyrillic letters) and `ss02` (Serbian/Macedonian variant of Cyrillc letter be) as far as I can see, so you could also use `ss03` for the custom feature actually, since `xnum` is not really standardized.

Comment: @rallg -- Of course proper-sized digits will look better, while oldstyle might look rather odd.  But the point about not traditional just meant that it's not surprising there's no standard procedure for OpenType.  Maybe this will catch on.